# ANTLR4 self and mutual left-recursion

Tags: antlr4, left-recursion, mutual-recursion

Is there a simple transformation or workaround to make this work in ANTLR4?

```
a : a p
  | b q
  | c
  ;

b : b r
  | a s
  | d
  ;
```

That is, `a` and `b` are self-left-recursive and mutual-left-recursive, the other rules (`c`, `d`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`) are just placeholders for simple rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove direct left recursion from both rules. Let's consider the rule `a`:

```
a
    : (b q | c) p+
    | b q
    | c
    ;
```

Simplify:

```
a
    : (b q | c) p*
    ;
```

Do a similar transformation for the rule `b`:

```
b
    : (a s | d) r*
    ;
```

Now it's possible to replace `b` identifier in rule `a` with the body of rule `b`:

```
a
    : (c | (a s | d) r* q) p*
    ;
```

Or to replace `a` identifier in rule `b` with the body of rule `a`:

```
b
    : ((b q | c) p* s | d) r*
    ;
```

It's also possible to get rid of direct left recursion if needed.